# What is a struct variant enum in std:serialize?

Tags: rust

I am implementing my own `serialize::{Encoder,Decoder}`. There is a [`emit_enum_struct_variant`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/serialize/trait.Encoder.html#tymethod.emit_enum_struct_variant) method in `serialize::Encoder`. I want to know what kind of object will trigger this method.

I thought its objects looked like this:

```
struct Point {
    x: int,
    y: int,
}

enum MyEnum {
    StructValue(Point),
}
```

Which actually trigger these methods in order:

```
emit_enum(name=MyEnum)
emit_enum_variant(v_name=StructValue,v_id=0,len=1)
emit_enum_variant_arg(a_idx=0)
emit_struct(name=Point,len=2)
emit_struct_field(f_name=x,f_idx=0)
emit_struct_field(f_name=y,f_idx=1)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Enum struct variant is an enum variant of this form:

```
enum MyEnum {
    StructValue { x: int, y: int }
}
```

That is, enum variant resemble not a tuple struct, but a regular structure. Such variants are occasionally useful when enum variant holds more than few fields, or when it is semantically more correct (e.g. a variant which contains several fields of the same type).

Comment: Sorry for this trivial question. What about ```emit_tuple_struct```? I tried ```struct TupleStruct(uint, bool);``` which invoke ```emit_struct```.

Comment: I just checked and indeed, `#[deriving(Decodable, Encodable)]` uses `emit_struct`/`read_struct` instead of `emit_tuple_struct`/`read_tuple_struct`. I don't know the reason why it happens, maybe it can be found in the git history of the library which contains `#[deriving(Encodable, Decodable)]` implementation.